# Testing viewpager with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a viewpager and I want to check for an imageview in it. I have used following code but its not working.

> onView(allOf(withId(R.id.img_flag), hasSibling(withText("some
>   text"))));

- this one always returns true

> onView(withId(R.id.img_flag)).check(doesNotExist());

- this one throws AmbiguousViewMatcherException

Comment: so what is a question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're going to check, but to resume:

1. The first one is always `true`, because `img_flag` would be certainly always (I mean: until you put it in another `ViewGroup`) a sibling to a `TextView` with `some text`. It's like mathematical `2+2=4`.

   So this test only checked if `img_flag` has sibling with `"some text"`.
2. `AmbiguousViewMatcherException` means only that there are more than one view with `img_flag` id. Espresso don't know which of them shoul not exist so it informs about it.

If you wanna fix the second one please read about `onData()` Espresso matcher.

Visit also these sites:

- https://guides.codepath.com/android/UI-Testing-with-Espresso
- https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/index.html

On the second one you would find [Espresso Cheat Sheet](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/downloads/espresso-cheat-sheet-2.1.0.pdf), where struct of `onData()` matcher is enough explained

If you have more quesrtions, please feel free to ask.